# What's wrong with my CGBitmapContext?

Tags: python, macos, core-graphics

I having trouble creating a valid CGBitmapContext in python. It's just returning null values, which then causes everything else to complain about the lack of definition and python crashes. I've tried setting the memory allocation to None, which means it's supposed to sort itself out, but that doesn't work either. And I don't think the objC buffer is being allocated either. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os, sys, objc
from Quartz import *

os.environ["CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE"] = '1'
resolution = 300 #dpi
scale = resolution/72

cs = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceSRGB)
# Options might be: kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast \ or FIRST
transparency = kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast

#Save image to file
def writeImage (image, url, type, options):
    destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(url, type, 1, None)
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, image, options)
    CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination)
    CFRelease(destination)
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':

    for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
        pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename(filename))
        numPages = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(pdf)
        shortName = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]

        # For each page, create a file
        for i in range (1, numPages+1):
            page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, i)
            if page:
        #Get mediabox
                mediaBox = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, kCGPDFMediaBox)
                x = CGRectGetWidth(mediaBox)
                y = CGRectGetHeight(mediaBox)
                x *= scale
                y *= scale
        # Allocate Memory, in this day and age.
                try:
                    rasterData = objc.allocateBuffer(int(4 * x * y))
                except  MemoryError: break
        # Create a Bitmap Context
                ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(rasterData, x, y, 8, x, cs, transparency)
                CGContextSaveGState (ctx)
                CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, scale,scale)
                CGContextDrawPDFPage(ctx, page)
                CGContextRestoreGState(ctx)
        # Convert to an "Image"
                image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx) 
        # Create unique filename per page
                outFile = shortName + str(i) + ".tiff"
                url = CFURLCreateFromFileSystemRepresentation(kCFAllocatorDefault, outFile, len(outFile), False)
        # kUTTypeJPEG, kUTTypeTIFF, kUTTypePNG
                type = 'kUTTypeTIFF'
                options = {
                    kCGImagePropertyTIFFXResolution : 300,
                    kCGImagePropertyTIFFYResolution : 300
                    }
                writeImage (image, url, type, options)
                CGContextRelease(ctx)
                del page
```

Comment: The `bytesPerRow` argument to `CGBitmapContextCreate` looks wrong. If your bitmap is `x` pixels wide, and it's an RGBA context with 8 bits per component, each pixel takes 4 bytes and thus bytesPerRow should be `x * 4`. (Note that when you allocated the memory, you did the math correctly.)

Comment: Yes, I've just put 0 to get the Mac to work it out for itself, and  the script seems to be failing elsewhere now. So, progress.

Answer (score 0):

The output suggested that I turn on some extra logging:

```
os.environ["CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE"] = '1'
os.environ["CGBITMAP_CONTEXT_LOG_ERRORS"] = '1'
```

This then gave me the following information, which is seemingly lacking from Apple's own documentation:

```
CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported parameter combination:
    16 integer bits/component;
    48 bits/pixel;
    RGB color space model; kCGImageAlphaNone;
    14336 bytes/row.
Valid parameters for RGB color space model are:
    16  bits per pixel,      5  bits per component,      kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst
    32  bits per pixel,      8  bits per component,      kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst
    32  bits per pixel,      8  bits per component,      kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast
    32  bits per pixel,      8  bits per component,      kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst
    32  bits per pixel,      8  bits per component,      kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast
    64  bits per pixel,      16 bits per component,      kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast
    64  bits per pixel,      16 bits per component,      kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast
    64  bits per pixel,      16 bits per component,      kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast|kCGBitmapFloatComponents
    64  bits per pixel,      16 bits per component,      kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast|kCGBitmapFloatComponents
    128 bits per pixel,      32 bits per component,      kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast|kCGBitmapFloatComponents
    128 bits per pixel,      32 bits per component,      kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast|kCGBitmapFloatComponents
```

So merely changing the transparency constant to kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast has stopped the crashing and fixed the context. However, the script as a whole still doesn't work, and I just get `Trace/BPT trap: 5` as a response.